# stuck on a level of Think Different

Tags: think-different

How do I complete a level of think different. I have tried adding, multiplying, subtracting, dividing. I am clearly not thinking differently.

Question to solve is 2+3=8, 3+7=27, 4+5=32, 5+8=60, 6+7=72, 7+8=?

Comment: Not only is this in the answer sheet listed on the tag wiki, but the answer comes up many times, including 1st 2nd and 3rd, when the question is copied into google directly from this post.

Comment: @Timelord64 This is a new user. I'm not. I wasn't aware that information like this was included in tag wikis, and after trying to find the info there I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this level is asking for x * (x + y - 1), so "7 + 8" should be 7 * (7 + 8 - 1) = 7 * 14 = 98.

Comment: Why the -1? This seems correct. (added a +1). I actually find this answer better than the one with "invisible incrementable number" since it does not depend on the equalities order, so it holds even if you change places between them.